# Private docker.io registry in microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s, containerd

I have issue with microk8s hitting rate limit for docker.io registry

```
ctr: failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/calico/kube-controllers/manifests/sha256:bf58609ff39089533b80ff2a10fffd1302346f153c66e24d0572fb8b198daea1: 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
```

I wanted to configure private repository authorization for docker.io. I've followed [following instruction](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/docs/cri/registry.md)

It looks like that it's not working with docker.io registry

I've modified configuration file

`/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/containerd-template.toml`

with following content

```
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
    # 'plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors' are namespace to mirror mapping for all namespaces.
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."docker.io"]
        endpoint = ["https://registry-1.docker.io", ]
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."docker.io".auth]
        username = ""
        password = ""            
        auth = ""
        email = ""
```

However it looks like this is not working for docker.io registry

I'm aware of [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/) solution, however if I recall correctly this needs to be applied to every namespace separately. I'm looking for a one-shot solution for whole kubernetes cluster.

Is there such solution, or kubernetes secrets are the only way to go ?

Comment: I am not sure if you understand the error message. It is not something you are going to solve. That's a limit that has got docker server that you have hit. Any solution, besides increasing the rate limit, is going to be considered a `hack`.

Comment: Docker impose rate limit because my requests to registry are not authenticated. If you authenticate with your credentials, you are not subject to general rate limit. Due to lack of ability to authenticate, I can not use account based rate limits